# Where are the settings that determine the meaning of the mouse wheel?

Tags: mouse-wheel

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.  I like to use the mouse wheel for scrolling through the contents of a window, but sometimes it unexpectedly switches desktops on me.  What setting controls the meaning of the mouse wheel?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find settings for mouse, touchpad and other [input] devices in SETTINGS, INPUT DEVICES.

However, I believe the setting you're looking for is in SETTINGS, WORKSPACE BEHAVIOR, VIRTUAL DESKTOPS.

Answer (score 0):

The mouse wheel, it seems, acts like repeated presses of the arrow keys and its effect is determined by the location of the cursor.  If you have multiple desktops and the cursor happens to be on the virtual desktop widget (one of the desktops accessible at the bottom of the screen), the mouse wheel runs through the virtual desktops. If it's on text, the mouse wheel scrolls the text up or down.   I don't know where this behavior is described, but I found it very useful once I understood it.